# Jquery validation for email exist in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, validation, email

I need to validate email id for weather its already exist or not

i have tried this code but it is not working and in inspect element it showing:

jquery-1.10.2.js:8706

POST http://localhost/selfcomply/public/admin/companymaster/check_email.php 405 (Method Not Allowed) and

MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

validation.js file

```
$("#companydata").validate
({
    rules: {
        company_email:{
            required: true,
            emailer: true,
            remote:{
                url:"check_email.php",
                type:"post"
            }
                },

    messages:{

        company_email:{
            required: "Please enter the email address  ",
            remote:"Already Exist"
        },

    }
});
```

check_email.php

```
  $email = "'".$_POST["emails"]."'";
  $showmember = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT count(company_email) as countemail FROM tbl_company_master WHERE company_email = ".$email.""));
  if($showmember[0]->countemail > 0)
  {
      return "false";
  }
  else
  {
    return "true";
  }
```

weather i need to give path in route.php or not, but i dont think so

Comment: The error means that you're trying to `POST` to a request, but the route doesn't allow any `POST` requests. Do you use Laravel? If so, dump your route or route files here.

Comment: i have not written any route in route.php @DeesOomens

Answer (score 0):

If you are using laravel, than change:

```
url:"check_email.php",    // This is the core php way of passing the file name here
```

to

```
url: "/checkemail",  // In laravel, you have to pass a route here
```

for this you have to make a `get` route defined in routes like:

```
Route::get('/checkemail', 'MyController@myFunction');
```

here `myFunction` is a function defined in `MyController`, that returns either `true/false` based on the email checking logic.

Comment: I have tried but its showing in inspect element console that  "The requested URL was not found on this server." @Mayank

​

Answer (score 0):

You could check if email exists directly in your query (powered by Eloquent ORM):

change here:

```
  remote:{
          url:"checkEmail",
          type:"post"
        }
```

and also change in the route.php,

```
 Route::post('/checkEmail', 'MyController@checkEmailvalid');
```

than in the php controller

```
public function checkEmailvalid()
 {
   $user = User::all()->where('email', Input::get('email'))->first();
  if ($user) {
    return Response::json(Input::get('email').' is already taken');
   } else {
    return Response::json(Input::get('email').' Username is available');
  }
 }
```

Comment: I have tried above solution but in console m seeing error "MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:"   and   there is no error message or validation message displayed in front end.

Comment: what is your controller name ? Place this function checkEmailvalid() into that controller, and change the name of controller in the routes.php